# Gracenote Entourage RESTful api

Tags: gracenote

I'm coding a cross-platform client in Adobe Air.  Native SDKs don't suit me, obviously.

Is there an API to query Entourage?

Comment: is there nothing on https://developer.gracenote.com/ that helps?

Comment: I develop using cross-platform SDK, therefore native SDKs for ACR don't cut for me.

Answer (score 0):

No, Entourage is an SDK and not a Web API. In order to identify television content, Entourage needs to listen to an audio stream and perform some signal processing/fingerprinting on it, which is best done with a native SDK.

If you just need to look up TV listing data, there is the eyeQ API (https://developer.gracenote.com/eyeq)

Comment: What if I use cross-platform app development SDK ? Am I out of luck? I mean the app stream captured audio data from device to Gracenote service just as in native SDK.

Comment: Entourage is only available on Android and iOS as native SDKs. If by cross-platform you means those two platforms then you could embed the respective native dlls into you air builds. If you plan to use Entourage on other platforms, you are out of luck as of today.